# redirect 301 with RewriteRule (for Joomla with params)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

To redirect a joomla native link:

> http://somesite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40

=>

> http://somesite.com/epr/active-requests

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests? [NC,R=301]
```

I need to redirect joomla article with additional URL parameter - RQNB:

Link 1:

> http://somesite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40&PARAM1=dummy&RQNB=1111&PG=REQ

=>

> http://somesite.com/epr/active-requests?RQNB=1111

Link 2:

> http://somesite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=152&Itemid=40&PARAM1=dummy&RQNB=2222&PG=REQ

=>

> http://somesite.com/dr/active-requests?RQNB=2222

Please note Link1 and Link2 are pointing to different applications:

1) http://somesite.com/epr/active-requests?RQNB=1111

2) http://somesite.com/dr/active-requests?RQNB=2222

How do I add param condition to htaccess? Do I need another row of RewriteCond? Thanks.

EDIT:

The dirty link could have some other unwanted params (like &PG=REQ), I need to capture only RQNB:

http://somesite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40&RQNB=1111&PG=REQ

EDIT2:

Tried this, but it does not work...
1st row: capture everything after "&Itemid=40"
2nd row: capture from 1st row result only &RQNB

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^RQNB=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?RQNB=%2 [NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture groups from the query string, and reference them using %1

Something like that should work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40&RQNB=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?RQNB=%1 [NC,R=301]
```

If you have more parameters after the RQNB, then the following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^RQNB=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &RQNB=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?RQNB=%1 [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you, yes I just came up with same approach, but realized that the link can have some other unwanted params, please see the EDIT

Comment: is there any way to have a relationship between option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40 and /epr/active-requests? Because I will have other old links to point (with RQNB param).

Comment: I don't understand your question. What urls would you like to rewrite ? And where to ?

Comment: please see the question, I have edited it explaining about link1 and link2.

Comment: If I will use your last version of solution and having multiple articles that should be pointing to different apps => I cannot distinguish relationship between joomla native link <=> sef link

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021538/extract-url-parameter-with-regex)
my working solution is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|\b)(RQNB=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?%1 [NC,R=301]
```