# Extract URL parameter with regex

Tags: regex

string - URL:

```
1. &PARAM1=dummy&RQNB=EPR-0-1&PG=REQ //need to extract RQNB=EPR-0-1
2. &PARAM1=dummy&PG=REQ&RQNB=EPR-0-2 //need to extract RQNB=EPR-0-2
3. &RQNB=EPR-0-3&PARAM1=dummy&PG=REQ //need to extract RQNB=EPR-0-3
```

Need to extract RQNB=dyn_value.
Will use in mod_rewrite for apache.

"RQNB=dyn_value" can appear in any position of the string

Tried:

```
^.*[&]?RQNB=(.*)$
```

but that extracts:

```
1) RQNB=EPR-0-1&PG=REQ
2) RQNB=EPR-0-2
3) RQNB=EPR-0-3&PARAM1=dummy&PG=REQ
```

Comment: What work have you done to attempt to solve this yourself? And more importantly, why aren't you using a library that already knows how to parse URLs?

Comment: posted what I tried. I will use in mod_rewrite for apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
(^|\b)RQNB=[^&]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pzR_wYnrflON4XwA)

**Edit:**

Based on your comments below, you need to capture the string by enclosing it in `(` and `)`, like so:

```
(?:^|\b)(RQNB=[^&]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6CcmDGyCI-bypczm)

Then, you can refer to `RQNB=foo` using a number group indicator, like `$1`.

Comment: Will use in mod_rewrite for apache.

Comment: To use it in a `RewriteCond`, you are going to want to capture the information somehow using a group (with parentheses). Do you want to capture the entire string `RQNB=foo`, just `foo`, or `RQNB` and `foo` separately?

Comment: thanks a lot! that works! just curious, how to change the regex if I need only foo, but not RQNB=foo

Comment: Just move the first parenthesis, like this: `(?:^|\b)RQNB=([^&]+)`. Glad it helped! Please remember to accept an answer.

Comment: Ed: this is not in the scope of this q, but I tried to capture 2 params: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=40(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|\b)(RQNB=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|\b)(PG=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?%1%2 [NC,R=301]

Comment: in %1 is stored PG=REQ and in %2-nothing. the reference is lost somehow... any ideas?

Comment: You need a combined RewriteCond, not two conditions.

Comment: Ed: you are right.. tried (.*)(?:^|\b)(RQNB=[^&]+|PG=[^&]+) but it's not good.. still searching..

Comment: `(.*)(?:^|\b)(RQNB=[^&]+|PG=[^&]+)` matches `.*` (first group) and either `RQNB=[^&]+` or `PG=[^&]+`, but not both. You want something like `(?:^|\b)(PG=[^&]+)&(?:.+&)?(RQNB=[^&]+)`.  [**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uW3wD7)

Comment: Ed: thanks! for some reason PG is in %1 and RQNB is in %3; %2 is empty.. don't know why.

Comment: Be sure you're using the one currently in my comment; it had a typo (missing `?:`) that I fixed a moment after I posted it.

Comment: Ed: awesome! God bless you! Thanks!

Comment: Ed: sorry for bothering, just noticed that (?:^|\b)(PG=[^&]+)&(?:.+&)?(RQNB=[^&]+) is good when &PG=REQ inside params is before &RQNB=EPR-0-1. If &RQNB=EPR-0-1 comes first and then &PG=REQ: this situation is not covered in this regex.

Comment: You're right. You need to do one of two things: (1) use two rules, one for each order of the arguments, or (2) use a combined rule that tests both possibilities. A demo of the latter is [here](http://regex101.com/r/aN2pT4). If you go that route, you may have data in four places (%1, %2, %3, %4), so your rule would have to look something like `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /epr/active-requests?%1%2%3%4 [NC,R=301]`. You're better off doing two rules to keep this from balooning in complexity, if you can't control the order of the parameters. Ultimately, this logic may need to be in your app itself.